# Server Error in '/' Application <nativehr>0x81020030</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to upload a ms word or pdf document document on SharePoint it giving the below error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   0x81020030The URL
>   'SOPs/WP_Themes.xlsx' is invalid.  It may refer to a nonexistent file
>   or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the
>   current Web. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
>   0x81020030The URL
>   'SOPs/WP_Themes.xlsx' is invalid.  It may refer to a nonexistent file
>   or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the
>   current Web.
>
> Source Error:  An unhandled exception was generated during the
>   execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin
>   and location of the exception can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below. Stack Trace:   [COMException (0x81020030):
>   0x81020030The URL
>   'SOPs/WP_Themes.xlsx' is invalid.  It may refer to a nonexistent file
>   or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the
>   current Web.]
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.AddOrUpdateItem(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate,
>   Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion, Boolean
>   bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId,
>   Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames,
>   Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean
>   bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bUnRestrictedUpdateInProgress,
>   Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName,
>   ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter
>   pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback) +0
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl,
>   String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean
>   bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion, Boolean
>   bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId,
>   Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames,
>   Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean
>   bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bUnRestrictedUpdateInProgress,
>   Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName,
>   ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter
>   pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback)
>   +409
>
> [SPException: The URL 'SOPs/WP_Themes.xlsx' is invalid.  It may refer
>   to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder
>   that is not in the current Web.]
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
>   +36771718    Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl,
>   String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean
>   bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion, Boolean
>   bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId,
>   Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames,
>   Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean
>   bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bUnRestrictedUpdateInProgress,
>   Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName,
>   ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter
>   pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback)
>   +1634    Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.AddOrUpdateItem(Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystem, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bNoVersion,
>   Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean
>   bCheckin, Guid newGuidOnAdd, Int32& ulID, Object& objAttachmentNames,
>   Object& objAttachmentContents, Boolean suppressAfterEvents, String
>   filename, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion) +2764
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.UpdateInternal(Boolean bSystem,
>   Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Guid newGuidOnAdd, Boolean bMigration,
>   Boolean bPublish, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean
>   bCheckin, Boolean suppressAfterEvents, String filename, Boolean
>   bPreserveItemUIVersion) +723
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.Update() +131
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SaveButton.SaveItem(SPContext
>   itemContext, Boolean uploadMode, String checkInComment) +2103
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SaveButton.OnBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs e) +849
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args)
>   +50    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1665
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.7.2623.0 I am trying to upload the document on
>   SharePoint it giving the above error.

Any idea on the above error ?

Comment: I'm confused! is it SharePoint online or on-prem issue? please edit the tags and specify your current SP version?

Comment: @MohamedEl-QassasMVP this is SharePoint online

Comment: The question has been opened again :)

Comment: @MohamedEl-QassasMVP, Any idea about the above problem ? I am using SharePoint online 2013.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems caused by disk-space issue , but you are in online environment , so you'd better contact MS support team and submit a ticket to them .

If you are global administrator you can raise the case from Admin center , as i know , it will be free charge .